# Flutter: IOS App Size is 5X than that of Android

Tags: flutter

When building my Flutter app to Android, the app size (on a real device, release mode) is roughly 65MB, while on IOS the size is 250+MB

The question is, why do these numbers vary so much?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Turns out I compared Android Release version to IOS Debug version